# Remove gray/grey shadow from Leaflet map in R

Tags: r, dictionary, leaflet

Folks, I have a problem. My map has an unusual gray shadow.
I use shapefiles

```
countries <- readOGR(".","ne_50m_admin_0_countries")
```

or geojson

```
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/geo-countries/master/data/countries.geojson"
countries <- geojson_read(url, what = "sp")
```

Does not matter, both have the same error.

[image]

I had this issue before but did not find a sustainable solution and my search did not help, that is why I am here.

How do I color?

```
# Color palette
colorFactors = colorFactor(c('red', 'orange', 'blue', 'green'),
                      domain = dfs_pg$Region)

# Create a map
leaflet(dfs_pg) %>%
addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
addPolygons(stroke = FALSE, 
          fillOpacity = 0.75, 
          color = colorFactors(dfs_pg$Region), weight = 1)
```

There are multiple NAs and I tried to omit them - did not work for me. I want to keep NAs the same color as the original provider without this shadow.

I merge my csv and geojson into a spatial dataframe.

The same problem is for ANY provider.

Really appreciate your help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with a help of R community perfectly. enter image description here

Treating NAs was a key:

"If you look at data_pg_df$Region, you'll see it has many NAs:

```
> data_pg_df$Region
[1] NA              NA              NA              NA              NA             
[6] NA              NA              NA              "Latin America" NA             
[11] NA              NA              NA              NA              NA             
[16] NA              NA              NA              NA              NA             
[21] NA              NA              NA              NA              NA             
[26] NA              NA              NA              NA              NA             
[31] NA              NA              NA              NA              NA             
[36] NA              NA              NA              "North America" NA             
[41] NA              "Asia"          NA              NA              NA             
[46] NA              NA              NA              NA              NA             
[51] NA              NA              NA              NA              NA             
[56] NA              NA              "Europe"        NA              NA             
[61] NA              NA              NA              NA              NA          
...
```

With data_pg_df$Region == input$regionInput, you're comparing it to a value, like 
    "Asia". In R, if you compare a value to NA, you get NA.

```
> data_pg_df$Region == "Asia"
[1]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA FALSE    NA    NA    NA    NA    
NA    NA
[16]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    
NA    NA
[31]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA FALSE    NA    NA  TRUE    NA    
NA    NA
[46]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA FALSE    
NA    NA
[61]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    
NA    NA
...
```

And you can't index into data_pg_df object using NA.

You'll need to handle the NAs somehow. I don't know for sure what's appropriate for your data set, but it looks like you might want to keep only the rows where == resolves to TRUE, and drop the rows which would result in NA and FALSE. To do this, you can add in a check with is.na():

```
!is.na(data_pg_df$Region) & data_pg_df$Region == "Asia"
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
FALSE FALSE
[16] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
FALSE FALSE
[31] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE 
FALSE FALSE
[46] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
FALSE FALSE
[61] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
FALSE FALSE
```

...
So then you'd have:

```
selectedRegion <- reactive({
data_pg_df[!is.na(data_pg_df$Region) & data_pg_df$Region == input$regionInput, ]
})"
```

[image]